# Batch code to run a file on Log On Windows 10 Home

Tags: batch, login-screen

Is there a batch file command I can use to run a file or command, not on boot but on Logon (like resume from sleep)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use for this the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page).

The Scheduler can execute scripts or programs that are triggered by a condition such as
logon.

References :

- [Starting an Executable When a User Logs On](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/starting-an-executable-when-a-user-logs-on)
- [Logon Trigger Example (Scripting)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/logon-trigger-example--scripting-)

Comment: How exactly would I do this from a batch file?

Comment: I suppose I could modify the vbscript and then run that.

Comment: You don't - you specify in the scheduler the batch file to be executed. Just remember that it will by default execute as administrator.

Comment: Well I need to know how to do this from a batch file. I am not trying to start a batch file on log on.

Comment: This might help : [How to Create, Modify and Delete Scheduled Tasks from the Command Line](https://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/).